# logging stats in game development

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, game-center

i'm in the early stages of my first game for iOS.

i wonder how you guys log all your statistics for the game. currently i'm only using gamecenter to track the highscore.

take a look for example at a new game called "astronuts"

[image]

what do you think i should use and what has enough performance?

i thought about coreData, but i don't know.

thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could write it to a plist, but really, is there any reason for you not to use CoreData?

Comment: hmm. my project started without "use coredata for ...". so i don't know how much work it is, to implement coredata afterwards

Comment: its not a massive amount. you would need to set up your data model, persistent store coordinator, and object context, but most of the code could be copy and pasted from one of the templates. it depends on how much data you want to persist. ie if its only 10 fields, you may find that storing it in NSUserDefaults or similar would suit you better.

Comment: yeah i also thought about `NSUserDefaults`, but i think, its not the right place for this. i'll setup a list with all stats i want to log, depending on this, i will choose the method

Comment: I would seriously consider core data, it will allow you to track a lot more stats, even if you don't make them visible to the user in this version.

Comment: also a +1 for CoreData could be versioning. you can easily update the structure if something changes in a future version

Comment: be careful about how many times you update the version, as if someone updates from version 1 straight to version 3 it doesn't go from v1->v2->v3, it goes straight from v1->v3 and if there is a big enough difference, then it can fail.its a fringe case, but one to be aware of.

Comment: you can also setup transitions from 1 to 3 f.e.

Comment: its definitely possible, but make sure you keep a copy of the datafile for each version, so you can test.

Comment: i'll accept your answer, i don't think any other ideas are showing up here. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Core data is the way to go here. It will make your code cleaner and perform better. I work in game development and this is the advice I always give in this situation.